# Error: Webpack Compilation Error while using function from custom typescript library

Tags: typescript, webpack, cypress

I created a custom library in typescript and then loaded it (via package.json) to the UI tests repository, which is written with the usage of typescript and cypress.

When I want to use some function from my library in UI repository, just running the cypress test I am getting this error:

```html
Error: Webpack Compilation Error
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (4:15)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| export { createNewProject } from './src/helpers/loan-booking/create-project'
> const globalAny: any = global;
```

Apparently, for some reason typescript code from my library cannot be appropriately compiled with cypress tests in another repo.

What I did:

In UI tests repository I created a webpack config.

```
webpack.config.ts
```

```html
import path from 'path';

module.exports = {
  entry: './',

  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'main.js',
  },

  // file resolutions
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.ts', '.tsx'],
    symlinks: false,
    cacheWithContext: false,
    fallback: {
      fs: false,
      path: false,
      os: false,
      util: false,
      stackUtils: false,
      buffer: false,
      stream: false,
      crypto: false,
      process: false,
      url: false,
      constants: false,
      assert: false,
    },
  },

  // loaders
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'ts-loader',
            options: { transpileOnly: true },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

```
package.json
```

```html
{
    "type": "commonjs",
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.18.9",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.9",
        "@commitlint/cli": "^16.2.3",
        "@commitlint/config-conventional": "^16.2.1",
        "@faker-js/faker": "^6.3.1",
        "@types/fs-extra": "^9.0.13",
        "@types/webpack-node-externals": "^2.5.3",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.15.0",
        "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
        "cypress-file-upload": "^5.0.2",
        "cypress-mailosaur": "^2.3.3",
        "cypress-recurse": "^1.13.1",
        "cypress-wait-until": "^1.7.2",
        "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
        "dotenv-cli": "^5.1.0",
        "eslint": "^7.32.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
        "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^2.5.0",
        "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.12.1",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.4",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
        "custom-qa-library-common": "file:../custom-qa-library-common",
        "husky": "^7.0.4",
        "lint-staged": "^12.3.7",
        "prettier": "^2.6.0",
        "prettier-eslint": "^13.0.0",
        "webpack": "^5.74.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@cypress/commit-info": "^2.2.0",
        "@cypress/webpack-preprocessor": "^5.12.0",
        "cypress": "^9.7.0",
        "cypress-dotenv": "^2.0.0",
        "cypress-keycloak-commands": "^1.2.0",
        "dayjs": "^1.10.4",
        "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
        "fs-extra": "^9.1.0",
        "moment": "^2.29.4",
        "path": "^0.12.7",
        "require": "^0.4.4",
        "source-map-loader": "^4.0.0",
        "stack-utils": "^2.0.5",
        "ts-loader": "^9.3.1",
        "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
        "typescript": "^4.6.2",
        "uuid": "^8.3.2",
        "webpack-node-externals": "^3.0.0"
    }
}
```

```
tsconfig.json
```

```html
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["cypress", "node", "cypress-wait-until"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "allowJs": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
  },
  "include": ["cypress/**/*.ts", "cypress/**/*.js", ".eslintrc.js"]
}
```

And, the index.ts file from my custom library where the issue is pointed:

```html
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
export { createNewProject } from './src/helpers/loan-booking/create-project'
const globalAny: any = global;

const env = process.env.TEST_ENV || process.env.ENV || 'test.financing';
globalAny.testEnv = env;
const envvars: any = dotenv.config({ path: `${__dirname}/${env}.env` });

process.env.TZ = 'UTC';
let envvar: any;
const errors: any[] = [];

for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(envvars.parsed)) {
  try {
    envvar = val;
  } catch (e) {
    throw new Error('Error occurred while exporting variable');
  } finally {
    process.env[key] = envvar;
  }
}
```

I am not sure why my webpack config can't handle typescript properly, also I am a bit confused as my library is in node_modules, but this folder is excluded in webpack config.

Answer (score 0):

I solved that issue, finally, I didn't even need webpack config. My library was using expect package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/expect, which was giving me Webpack Compilation Error in cypress.

I replaced it with expect from chai and all errors are gone.